# Delphi 12: Why do I find this [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 Unable to execute ...?

Tags: android, delphi, sdk, runtime, delphi-12-athens

I am pretty new to Android compiling in Delphi, so take the time to explain thoroughly please.

Every time I want to run a test project I made, I get these errors:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 Unable to execute '"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\AndroidSDK\build-tools\29.0.3\aapt.exe" package -f -M "D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\AndroidManifest.xml" -F "D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\bin\RADHost-unaligned.apk" -I "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-29\android.jar" -S "D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\res" -A "D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\assets" "D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\library" "D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\classes"' (Error 1)
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\res\values-v31\styles.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon'.
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\res\values-v31\styles.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSplashScreenBackground'.
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 D:\Software\Delphi projects\Android\Release\RADHost\res\values-v31\styles.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor'.

I have no idea what I am doing and what to do next. Any assistance will help.

I tried googling the error, but everyone having this problem didn't really have a fix.

My SDK Manager's available build tools:

[image]

Comment: Please indicate what version of Delphi you're using.

Comment: Oh my bad, I edited it, I am using Delphi 12.

Comment: The problem is likely that your SDK is not configured correctly. You have it running build tools version 29.0.3 when the default for Delphi 12 is 33.0.2.

Comment: Okay thanks, this makes sense. Could you please look at the image I edited at the bottom. This is the only builds I have right now? What can I do next?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6nTL.png

Comment: I suggest using Tools | Manage Features (in the Delphi menu) to install the Android SDK, and configure Delphi to use that, because it seems you did not use this method when installing Delphi 12